# Browser scrollbar not appearing

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I have a problem where the browser scrollbar doesn't appear when my web content extends beyond the browser window. I'm pretty sure the problem is located in the container div and not the footer, as removing the footer doesn't change anything. Any suggestions?

Here's the html part.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
    <style>
    body {background-color:#64B6B1;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<div class="icon"><h2>AB</h2></div>
<ul>
<li><a href="webdesign.html"><div class="webdesign" style="background-color:#64B6B1;width:25px;height:25px;"></div></a></li>
<li><a href="graphicdesign.html"><div class="graphic"></div></a></li>
<li><a href="about.html"><div class="about"></div></a></li>
<li><a href="index.html"><div class="home"></div></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS part.

```
@charset "utf-8";

html {height:100%;}

body {
font-family:Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
color:#FFFFFF;
text-align:right;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}

h1 {font-family:Arial, sans-serif;}

.box {
width:390px;
height:300px;
float:left;
background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

#container {
position:absolute;
width:80%;
min-width:780px;
top:10%; right:0; left:0;
margin: auto;
padding:5px;
background-color:#000000;
}

/* FOOTER */

#footer {
width:100%;
height:50px;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
right:0;
z-index:10;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

ul {
list-style-type:none;
float:right;
margin:0;
padding:15px;
}

li {
display:inline;
float:right;
padding-left:10px;
}

div.home {
-moz-border-radius:50px/50px;
-webkit-border-radius:50px/50px;
border-radius:50px/50px;
background-color:#46433A;
width:20px;
height:20px;
transition:width 1s, height 1s, background-color 1s;
-webkit-transition:width 1s, height 1s, background-color 1s;
}

div.home:hover {
width:25px;
height:25px;
background-color:#8AB688;
}

div.about {
-moz-border-radius:50px/50px;
-webkit-border-radius:50px/50px;
border-radius:50px/50px;
background-color:#46433A;
width:20px;
height:20px;
transition:width 1s, height 1s, background-color 1s;
-webkit-transition:width 1s, height 1s, background-color 1s;
}

div.about:hover {
width:25px;
height:25px;
background-color:#DED4B9;
}

div.webdesign {
-moz-border-radius:50px/50px;
-webkit-border-radius:50px/50px;
border-radius:50px/50px;
background-color:#46433A;
width:20px;
height:20px;
transition:width 1s, height 1s, background-color 1s;
-webkit-transition:width 1s, height 1s, background-color 1s;
}

div.webdesign:hover {
width:25px;
height:25px;
background-color:#64B6B1;
}

div.graphic {
-moz-border-radius:50px/50px;
-webkit-border-radius:50px/50px;
border-radius:50px/50px;
background-color:#46433A;
width:20px;
height:20px;
transition:width 1s, height 1s, background-color 1s;
-webkit-transition:width 1s, height 1s, background-color 1s;
}

div.graphic:hover {
width:25px;
height:25px;
background-color:#CE534D;
}

div.icon {
-moz-border-radius:50px/50px;
-webkit-border-radius:50px/50px;
border-radius:50px/50px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width:35px;
height:35px;
float:left;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 4px;
border-style:double;
border-color:#46433A;
}

h2 {
font-size:18px;
font-family:Arial Narrow,sans-serif;
color:#46433A;
margin-top:7px;
margin-right:6px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

> I read "sidebar" as "scrollbar"; This answer solves a scrollbar problem.
>   Anyway, what the heck is "browser sidebar"?

---

```
body { ... overflow:hidden; ... }
```

should be

```
body { ... overflow:auto; ... }
```

or just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "sidebar" you are talking about is the black background of what is left over of the container after you add your `div class=box`'s to it. The reason it isn't showing is because you don't actually have a side bar div.

Add one <`div class="sidebar"></div>`

and the css, including `clearfix`, add the `clearfix` class to the parent container like such ...  `<div id="container clearfix">`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/qnq6S/)

```
.sidebar {
    width:200px;
    height:600px;
    background:red;
    float:right;
}

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I'm not talking about a div sidebar, what I meant was the sidebar for the actual browser. http://media.macbookjunkie.com/what-are-scrollbars/safari_with_vertical_scrollbar.gif

Comment: In that case it is not a "sidebar" but a "scrollbar". Obviously two very different things. Please rephrase your question as it is not clear enough.